# How to Accept '(" and ")" on Digits Only Accepted Textbox

Tags: c#, winforms, textbox

I have field where only digits are accepted but i want to same feature for another field (fax) where example values will look like (070) 412 34 56.

how can modify my current function so it also accepts "(" and ")" ?

here is current code i have to check digits

```
char ch = e.KeyChar;
if (!Char.IsDigit(ch) && ch != 8 && ch != 46)
{
    e.Handled = true;
}

e.Handled = !char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar) && !char.IsControl(e.KeyChar);
```

Comment: Use a regexp. In HTML5 it can even be in the browser. See e.g [this blog](http://blog.staffannoteberg.com/2012/03/01/html5-form-validation-with-regex/)

Comment: Read about regular expressions.

Comment: This is not a coding service. You try your best and we help if you have problems. "I don't know how" is not a problem statement. Give it a try.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One possibility:

Place every allowed character in a string and see if the entered character exists.

```
e.Handled = "0123456789()".IndexOf(e.KeyChar) < 0;
```

[`string.IndexOf`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.indexof%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) returns the index of the given char.
It returns -1 if the character was not found.